# How to use hyperlink inside ListView in Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink

I have simple `ListView` with 3-4 columns. One of the columns have an email address. I would like to be able to press that email address and open up any program which is associated with emails (most likely Outlook).

Is there a way to achieve that without external ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  try {
    string mailtoLink = "mailto:"+listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[email_Column].Text;
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(mailtoLink);
  } catch(Win32Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("An error has occured: "+ ex.Message);
  }
}
```

The email is of the format: user@domain.com

Comment: You need to fix it with `SubItems[Column].Text like this: listViewKlienciKontakty.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;

Comment: Well no, *you* need to fix it with that, but i changed it anyway :P

Comment: Yeah I changed it (by testing your solution). Thanks a lot for help!!