# Can I display links in a ListView's detail mode?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, hyperlink

In my windows application, I have a listview, which contains two columns. One of the subitem in a row contains the data as below.

```
 "Failed testcase path=C:\temp\test.jpg"
```

I need to provide hyperlink to only `C:\temp\test.jpg`. If I click on the same, it should open the corresponding image. 
 I tried by changing the property `HotTracking` to `true`.

```
listView1.HotTracking = true;
```

But it shows hyperlinks to all the rows in listview.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You'll need to paint the text yourself

Comment: Check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5103351/468718) can help you ?

Comment: BTW: you have exactly same question title as question asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2288404/468718) and I think answer provided [there](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2288404/468718) applies to your question also.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ObjectListView](https://web.archive.org/web/20161121000010/http://www.codeproject.com:80/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) -- an open source wrapper around a standard ListView. It supports links directly:

[image]
<sub>(source: [codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView/hyperlinks.png))</sub>

[This](https://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-do-i-show-a-hyperlink-in-a-cell) documents the simple process and how you can customize it.